# How to load a class from a .cs file

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, dynamic

Is it possible to load a class and create Instance of it from It's `.cs` file?

I want to open a custom class in a `.cs` file and create instance of it in my application

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in theory yes - it mainly depends on whether you have all dependencies available...

IF so you can use the built-in [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile the `.cs`- file to an assembly (can be purely in-memory if need be) and then use Reflection to create an instance/use a class from that assembly...

Since don't provide much detail I would suggest to checkout these links and come back with detail questions if some arrise:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655/en-us
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codecompilation.aspx
- http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Compile-C-or-VB-source-code-run-time.html
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx
- http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/
- http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Reflection_Tutorial.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection-field
- [C# Reflection: How to get class reference from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` and `System.CodeDom` to execute code at runtime, there is an article about this code project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/runtimecompiling.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/Run-Time_Code_Generation1.aspx)