# Unity 5 loading scripts at runtime from build directory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to attach a script to a empty `gameObject` at `runtime` using `addComponent`.
But, I don't want to drag the script directly into the project, I want to first build the project and the go into the build folder and drag it there.
After the game starts, I want to load it from there and attach it to the empty `gameObject`.

Comment: What do you mean by loading them?

Comment: Getting the script from the build directory and attaching it using addComponent

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Anyways, you should edit your question and remove everything in it, then ask the question in a different way that people can understand. You can also post link to images to describe what you are trying to do. By doing this, you will likely get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand you, that's possible.

1. Read C# codes from a text file using
   `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(...)` or `Resources.Load(...) as TextAsset`.
2. Use `CSharpCodeProvider` to dynamically generate a dll.
3. Load the `Component` type from the dll into the AppDomain.
4. Create a object of the type.
5. Attach it to the gameObject.

More on this here:
[How to load a class from a .cs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018417/how-to-load-a-class-from-a-cs-file)

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was looking for.