# How PHP sentence looks on C#

Tags: c#, php

I do not know PHP, could anyone explain me how $data.$prop looks on C#?
If $data has "some_data" value and $prop has "some_other_data" value, the $data.$prop is "some_data.some_other_data", Right?

I would like to implement next line on C#: sha1(md5($data.$prop)). There is concatenation of strings inside of brackets?

Comment: I'm sorry how are you relating php with c#

Comment: @Christian, I have description of API on PHP. I am going to invoke required service via ASP.NET.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be hashing hashes.  It does *not* increases the security of those hashes.  You should just use a better hashing algorithm to begin with.

Comment: @Servy, I think you are right, but I need generate and send required hash value. Service will generate value by the same algorithm above and compare it. I just try to reproduce this algorithm on C# :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out more about SHA1 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) and about MD5 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx). In C# string concatenation is done with operator +. So if you have two variables named data and prop, both strings, you would concatenate them with the following code:

```
string result = data + prop;
```

You have the examples for using cryptography classes on the links provided.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the what `$data` and `$prop` are.

**If they are strings**

They will will be concatenated.

**If `$data` is a object and `$prop` is a property**

You need to look at reflection. See [C# Reflection: How to get class reference from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string) for more info.

Comment: In PHP, classes are typically not objects.  (There's reflection, but that is not at all affected by `.`, which is entirely a string operator.)

Comment: True. Mistake at my end. Will update post.

Comment: It is not property. There are two variables in my case.

Comment: Then they will be concatenated :-)