# how to create a list of classes where the class name is taken from the string in c#

Tags: c#, string, list, class

Don't ask me why, but I need to do the following:
`string cName = "ClassA";`
`List<cName> l = new List<cName>();`
How can I do it?

my code:
`public void MergeForm(List<object> lModel)`
`{`
            `string className = lModel[0].GetType().Name;`
**`List<className> list = new List<className>();`**
`}`
object - it is a class

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string

Comment: I don't like "Don't ask me why". If we know why, we can maybe offer a better solution. In software development theres almost always more then one road to rome.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Assemmbly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx):

```
var l = Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name == "ClassA").ToList();
```

If you have the full type name, you can use [`Assemmbly.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx).

If you have the full type name and assembly-qualified name, and the type you seek is in another assembly, then use [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's throws exception: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()

Comment: @Sultan Hard to guess. Perhaps show some more of your code. Also, the methods I've described are very commonly used, you shouldn't have any problems in finding some examples (starting with the links I provided).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have `List<cName>` as static type, but you can create the instance:

```
IList l = (IList)Activator
    .CreateInstance(typeof(List<>)
    .MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(cName)));
```

`cName` needs to be the fully qualified name, though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Type ac;
string cName = "ClassA";
switch (cName)
{
case "ClassA":
ac = typeof(ClassA);
break;
case "ClassB":
ac = typeof(ClassB);
break;
default:
ac = typeof(System.String);    
break;
}
var genericListType = typeof(List<>);
var specificListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(ac);
var l= Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType);
```