# Create reference to a class from a string variable

Tags: c#, .net

Here is what I need to do;

```
string className = "Customer";
List<className> myList = new List<className>();
```

className can be any of my Entity Framework classes. I have used Customer just as an example.

I hope this is possible. If so, how?

UPDATE:

I also need to use this approach for retrieving data from an Entity Framework dbContext. For example...

```
        string className = "Customer";
        var myData = db.Set<className>();
```

Sorry. Not sure if I should have created another question here or updated this one. Be gentle with me. I'm new here. :o)

Comment: Why do you need that at all? If you have such a requirement you know in 99.999% of all cases that you are using the wrong approach.

Comment: @Nikita can you provide an example please? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim, I have a generic method for wrapping JSON results and I don't want to duplicate my code for all the entities in the solution. If I can do what I have asked help for it would prevent a lot of redundant code. If that is 99.999% wrong then so be it.

Comment: You might as well just go with `List<object>` because that's what you're going to have to treat that list as in the rest of the code anyway.

Comment: What do you plan to use for the type of the reference? `object` or some other base class? Generics gets you the closest to a solution for the problem (try to use a covariant parameter, but then you can't use `List<>`)

Comment: Here's another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565018/how-to-create-a-list-of-classes-where-the-class-name-is-taken-from-the-string-in?lq=1

Comment: Thanks Tim. It looks like I should now ask a separate but similar question as I need to know if it is possible to reference an Entity Framework dbContext in the same way. I.e. by using a string variable. See my updated question above. Thank you. :o)

Answer (score 4):

If you want you can use reflection in this case, but I would think over another solution.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Namespace.ClassName");
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { type } );
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Comment: check this answer! thats how you can use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Type customerType = Type.GetType("this.is.a.namespace.Customer");
```

Related: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)