# C# Functions to accept arguments from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is an extension of a question I had beforehand

I have a specific function that I want to run, and it is located inside an XML File:

```
Console.WriteLine("Text for test, {0}, {1}", testWord, testWord2);
```

The text is stored in an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <world>
    <region name="TestRegion">
      <area name="TestArea">
        <building name="Outside">
          <room name="TutorialRoom">
            <textToDisplay>"Text for test, {0},{1}"</textToDisplay>
            <extraString>testWord,tesWord2</extraString>
          </room>
        </building>
      </area>
    </region>
  </world>
</root>
```

I can easily get the string data using LINQ

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\LocationDatabase.xml");

        var textToDisplay= xelement.Elements("world")
            .Elements("region").Where(region => (string)region.Attribute("name") == "TestRegion")
            .Elements("area").Where(area => (string)area.Attribute("name") == "TestArea")
            .Elements("building").Where(building => (string)building.Attribute("name") == "Outside")
            .Elements("room").Where(room => (string)room.Attribute("name") == "TutorialRoom")
            .Elements("textToDisplay");

        var extraString= xelement.Elements("world")
            .Elements("region").Where(region => (string)region.Attribute("name") == "TestRegion")
            .Elements("area").Where(area => (string)area.Attribute("name") == "TestArea")
            .Elements("building").Where(building => (string)building.Attribute("name") == "Outside")
            .Elements("room").Where(room => (string)room.Attribute("name") == "TutorialRoom")
            .Elements("extraString");
```

And this works completely fine. The issue I have is when I don't have a word in the XML file, but rather a property of a class. I have a singleton Player, and it has a autoproperty Name. To normally access it, I can just say:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your name is:", Player.Instance.Name);
```

But how do I, instead, keep this in the XML file? Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <world>
    <region name="TestRegion">
      <area name="TestArea">
        <building name="Outside">
          <room name="TutorialRoom">
            <textToDisplay>"Your name is: {0}"</textToDisplay>
            <extraString>Player.Instance.Name</extraString>
          </room>
        </building>
      </area>
    </region>
  </world>
</root>
```

When I use the past command, it simple thinks that whole section is a string, and outputs "Your name is: Player.Instance.Name"

An example using my own code:
[image]

The Player Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GuardsOfAetheria
{
    class Player
    {
        public enum Class
        {
            Melee,
            Magic,
            Ranged
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Class PlayerClass { get; set; }

        private static readonly Player instance = new Player();

        static Player()
        {
        }

        private Player()
        {
        }

        public static Player Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this?

**EDIT 1:**
I was able to do something similar using the following lines of code:

```
var typ = typeof(Player);
var prop = typ.GetProperty("Name");
var propVal = prop.GetValue(Player.Instance);

Console.WriteLine(((string)textToDisplay.First()).Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine), propVal);
```

This works fine, and gets the necessary data. The issue here is that in different parts, different classes have to be called `var typ = typeof(Player)`, and different instances have to be attributed `var propVal = prop.GetValue(Player.Instance)`. I can store the name of the class and instance I need to get from, but simply using a string that holds that data doesn't work, like below:

```
string className = "Player";

var typ = typeof(className);
var prop = typ.GetProperty("Name");
var propVal = prop.GetValue(Player.Instance);

Console.WriteLine(((string)textToDisplay.First()).Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine), propVal);
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: It would already be instantiated beforehand

Comment: `String.Split` and getting property via reflection for each section?

Comment: I can do String.Split, but what is reflection? @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, hello?

Comment: Google `C# reflection`

Comment: @ChuckSavage, I have, but it seems to be about getting the type of an object by simply knowing its name. How would that work in this situation?

Comment: You want to call a property of Player called Instance, and a property of Instance called Name, and the only way to do that through code via strings is with Reflection.

Comment: Could you give a small example for me to work with, so I can understand it better (most online websites seem to make it very complicated, messing around with Assembly)

Comment: So to get the Player object, you need to get the type via the "Player" string. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Player is a singleton object. I can access all its properties via Player.Instance. The property I want to access is called Name, which is a string property. Class info is in the question, at the bottom

Comment: Since you are putting `Player.Instance.Name` in the XML, I presumed you wanted to do a lookup on `Player`. If that is incorrect, why store it?

Comment: I would like to store the property Name incase I have a section in my game where the NPC talks to the player, and says their name. The code that holds the name is `public string Name { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Type player = Type.GetType("Player");
```

or

```
Type player = Type.GetType("myNamespace.Player");
```

[See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string/1044472#1044472)

Then you are going to have to get an instance of that type, see manipulating types. Then you will need to get the `PropertyInfo`'s for the type, then get the one you want `Instance`, etc for Instance object.

You will need to get into intimate detail of telling the compiler what object your working with and what properties you want to access. Reflection is a runtime compiled way of accessing objects. It is definitely more complicated than the run-of-the-mill program.

Comment: So that means what I want to do is kinda complicated?

Comment: See a tiny (powerful) example here https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/nXPath/Functions/FunctionBase.cs

Comment: I know I used it more in this library, trying to find it - not seeing it, but mostly the XPath part of the library is expressions - a separate code base.