# How to get class and call its static member from one of its instance variable?

Tags: c#

I have an object a created by someone else using the following

```
 classA a = new classA()
```

However I don't know a is classA or not inside some_function.

```
void some_function(Object a)
{

}
```

I am wondering from a, how can I get classA, and then call its static method?

Comment: Well you can call `a.getClass()` to get the class, then reflection to call the method - but if you already know it, why can't you just use `classA.staticMethod()`? You haven't really provided enough context here...

Comment: a can be created by someone else; I only have a passed in.

Comment: Right, so add all of that as context to the question. The reason your two answers so far haven't helped you is that the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: modified; hopeful it is clearer.

Comment: Not much. It would be more helpful if you would show the declaration of the method you're trying to write, where presumably you have a parameter of type `Object`. Ideally, show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. How do you know which method to call? Note that your title is very misleading, talking about instance variables... I see no indication that instance variables are useful here.

Comment: modified again, actually you are right; I am inside some function accept a as Object.

Comment: also Jon, no getClass() method; only getType() method.

Comment: Whoops, yes - that's one problem with not following naming conventions in your question - I thought it was Java not C#, having missed the tag...

Comment: And I still don't see a short but complete program or any way of knowing what the method you want to call looks like. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0):

For using static methods, you do not need to instantiate the class. Just call it using class name as variable.

If you are passed variable a then get the class same using

```
t = a.GetType().Name ;

if(t=="classA"){
  classA.thefunction();
} else if(t="classB){
  classB.thefunction();
}  //and so not...
```

and instantiate the class.

Comment: I know it; but I only have instance a; also, I am not sure it is classA. I would like to determine its class first.

Comment: thanks and it is close to my need; but the solution looks a little bit ugly, do you think so? I have to use a lot of if .. else? Is there better way?

Comment: reflection can be used to get the class reference cleanly, MethodInfo will help in getting the static method and invoke to run it. there is a stackoverflow link for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string

Comment: @AdamLee glad to know my answer helped you. I also proposed you advanced way to use in your current situation. Do not forget to accept my answer.