# How to add an object to a generic list property of an instance of a class using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, generic-list, mscorlib

I have a class structure below. I am getting this error. Am i missing something here?

> Object does not match target type.

Class Structure

```
public class Schedule
{
    public Schedule() { Name = ""; StartDate = DateTime.MinValue; LectureList = new List<Lecture>(); }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public List<Lecture> LectureList { get; set; }
}

public class Lecture
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Credit { get; set; }
}
```

What i am trying:

```
Schedule s = new Schedule();
Type t = Type.GetType("Lecture");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
obj.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(obj, "Math");
obj.GetType().GetProperty("Credit").SetValue(obj, 1);
PropertyInfo pi = s.GetType().GetProperty("LectureList");
Type ti = Type.GetType(pi.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
ti.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(pi, new object[] { obj });
```

Comment: While trying to reproduce the problem, I have found another problem. You set `Credit to `1` while it is a string. Change its type to int.

Comment: @stuartd there is a reason i use reflection right?

Comment: When I tried your piece of code, I got an null value after this statement 
Type t = Type.GetType("Lecture");

So obviously the next statement will throw an null ref exception, but the message what you got is different one's.

I could see the usage of Type.GetType might be the issue (if in case), then check out this below answer from Jon Skeet - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1044472/1966993

Comment: @Ganesh you should specify the namespace of Lecture class.

Comment: Hmm, I tried even with that also. But still I am getting null reference exception.

Here is the code which I have changed it,

Schedule s = new Schedule();
Type t = Type.GetType("SO._39161851.Lecture, SO._39161851");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

Comment: I got it, now it's working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
// gets metadata of List<Lecture>.Add method
var addMethod = pi.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add");

// retrieves current LectureList value to call Add method
var lectureList = pi.GetValue(s);

// calls s.LectureList.Add(obj);
addMethod.Invoke(lectureList, new object[] { obj });
```

UPD. Here's the fiddle [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PmjvyO).

Comment: You also don't need `Type.GetType` - just use `PropertyInfo.PropertyType`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you get the `Add` method of `List<Lecture>` and try to invoke it with `PropertyInfo` as the instance invoking the method.

Change:

```
ti.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(pi, new object[] { obj });
```

to:

```
object list = pi.GetValue(s);
ti.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, new object[] { obj });
```

That way `pi.GetValue(s)` gets the `List<Lecture>` itself from the [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) (which only represents the property itself along with its `get` and `set` methods, and invoke its `Add` method with your `object[]` as arguments.

---

One more thing. why using:

```
Type ti = Type.GetType(pi.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

When you can just use:

```
Type ti = pi.PropertyType;
```