# How to pass a type to a generic method at run-time

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass a type into a generic function by only knowing the type name.

```
public void Main()
{
    string typeName = "string";
    Test<typeName>();
}

public void Test<T>()
{
    // Do Work
}
```

Comment: @Steve Is there a way to do this without having to use reflection to invoke the generic method?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, Reflection is needed because you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: This might be an XY problem.  Why do you have type names in string format?  If it's only a few specific types, the absolute simplest would be to initialize a dictionary with the string names as keys and the types as values.  But... that's about the worst way to solve this, haha.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski I'm trying to create a generic RESTful web api. The webroute is /type/id and the method will have the type name as a string param. From there I can do "return repository<T>.Get(id);" This way I do not have 30 methods with identical code and only a different type

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski Not sure I follow, yourObject will always be a string. And I can create a Type type from the string name but that can't be used as a generic param

Comment: @user3953989 Yeah, I deleted my comment after I reread your question.  I don't think that "duplicate" will help you.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: [How to get class type from string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string)