# Having a string representation of a class name how do I pass it to a generic

Tags: c#, generics

I need to call a function with the prototype:

```
SomeFunc<T>()
```

and say I have a class of:

```
public class Person
{
}
```

I would call it as `SomeFunc<Person>()`. However I only have Person expressed as a string so for instance:

```
var classString = "Person";
```

So how do I convert `classString` so I can pass it for T?

Comment: A combination of `Type.GetType()` (or `Assembly.GetType()`), and `MethodInfo.CreateGenericMethod`

Comment: My question is: Can you rewrite your code to use a real class-type instead of a string?

Comment: what is strange is that you want to call a method expecting a generic (which is determined at compile time) with a parameter determined at runtime. Are you sure generics are what you are looking for?

Comment: @himbrombeere that question supposes we have a `Type` object, which we don't here. And anyway, OP probably shouldn't be doing what they think they want to do

Comment: @AakashM While I agree, I don´t think we should reopen this question, as it would be too broad anyway - we simply don´t know exactly why OP wants this. We **could** reopen if we knew.

Comment: The reason I have the string is that it is in a stream of data sent to me. From said string I need to decode some subsequent bytes that represent that class type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See Andrew & Jon's answers on this question.

[C# Reflection: How to get class reference from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string/1044474#1044474)

Someone should probably mark this as duplicate.

Comment: "Someone should probably mark this as duplicate." And why do you answer this question instead of voting to close it?

Comment: I did search SO before I posted but somehow that post did not come up. So I appreciate the immediate downvote (not). The linked SO has all the info I need so thanks @Michael

Comment: @HimBromBeere vote to close privilege is at 3k so I'm just a weeee bit short... And I find it more helpful to point OP in the right direction in the meantime.

Comment: @TheEdge I can´t see any downvotes on your question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Its the down vote in this answer I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type like this

```
var classString = "Person";
Type typeValue = Type.GetType(classString );
var type = type.AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

then call the function like this type

Haven't tried, but it should work

Comment: `GetType` will need a complete assembly-qualified name for your own types in another assembly. Simply passing `"Person"` will therefor not work. Apart from this your answer is only a small part of the actual solution, leaving everything related to the generic method asside.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's not true? https://dotnetfiddle.net/dmgkUw

Comment: @HimBromBeere if the type you're after is internal to the same assembly then you don't need the bells and whistles. Otherwise you would. We don't actually know where OP is trying to assign the type from